# Trying to remove title and profile from Pinterest “embed pin”

Tags: javascript, html, pinterest

I'm trying to add a Pinterest "embed pin" to my website but do not want any title or profile information visible.
I only want a single image to have the hover button, not other images on the same page.

I've tried using and modifying the code as provided on Pinterest:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
<a data-pin-do="embedPin" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/99360735500167749/"></a>
```

and

```
<iframe src="https://assets.pinterest.com/ext/embed.html?id=99360735500167749" height="454" width="236" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
```

I've been fiddling around with this for hours and haven't made any progress with it at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs5QE.jpg)

Comment: the link anne put is the complete answer :D

Answer (score 2):

Iframes can be a tricky element to work with. An iframe is basically an embedded web page of it's own, meaning inside the iframe you have new html, a new body tag etc. This is why any css you apply on your own page won't affect your iframe.

The only way to style your iframe is to use javascript to insert a stylesheet inside the iframe itself. Then you can use css to target the elements you want to hide, the same way you would usually do (for instance `display:none`) As your javascript needs to 'insert' this, you'll need to put any and all css inside that function.

Last time I had a similar problem I used this reference, it takes you through step by step how to go about this: https://redstapler.co/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe/

This is assuming you have the css skills to alter and style these elements. If you don't yet, I suggest you read into css and practice that first.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply Anne. I have given it a go.